# logstash kafka input multiple topics with different codecs

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash

this is my logstash conf

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "127.0.0.1:9092"
    topics => ["filebeat", "access"]
    group_id => "test-consumer-group"
    consumer_threads => 1
    decorate_events => true
  }
}
```

I have two topics but I want to use different codec for diffrent topic. how can I do this?

I try to add

```
    if ([topic] == "filebeat") {
      codec => "json"
    }
```

in the kafka input conf, the the logstash returns me errors.

```
Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, => at line 6, column 8 (byte 143) after input {\n  kafka {\n    bootstrap_servers => \"127.0.0.1:9092\"\n    topics => [\"filebeat\", \"access\"]\n    group_id => \"test-consumer-group\"\n    if "
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 separate kafka inputs with each a different codec.

One other option is to add a filter that parses the json object depending on the the topic

```
filter {
  if([topic] == "filebeat") {
    json {
      source => "message"
    }
  }
}
```

for more info check:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html

Comment: 2 kafka input works for me , but the filter way not work the me, it just put all the mesage into a json field, but what I need is put all json keys under the root.

Comment: Good to hear the 2 kafka inputs are working. For the filter you can experiment with adding `target => "doc"` although omitting it should write the result to the root object according to the documentation
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html#plugins-filters-json-target

Comment: try with `if [@metadata][kafka][topic] == "filebeat"`

Comment: Currently logstash also supports separate pipelines for each input stream. this makes the code more readable.
You can create a pipeline for every kafka topic input with its own output